# Как в 1с, значение введённое в поле ввода(реквизит2), находящееся на второй форме, передать на первую форму(реквизит1)?

Tags: 1с

Как в 1с, значение введённое в поле ввода(реквизит2), находящееся на второй форме, передать на первую форму(реквизит1)?

Comment: Как у вас связаны формы между собой? Одна форма вызывает другую?

Comment: На первой форме есть кнопка, нажатие на которую приводит к открытию второй, в которой есть поле ввода. Введя значение в это поле, я хочу, чтобы оно же отобразилось в реквизите поля первой формы.

Comment: Это произвольная форма или формы выбора?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в сторону параметра "ОписаниеОповещенияОЗакрытии" глобального метода "ОткрытьФорму" в синтакс-помощнике:

ОткрытьФорму(<ИмяФормы>, <Параметры>, <Владелец>, <Уникальность>, <Окно>, <НавигационнаяСсылка>, **<ОписаниеОповещенияОЗакрытии>**, <РежимОткрытияОкна>)

Во второй форме нужно вызывать закрытие с передачей параметра, тогда в первой сработает указанное оповещение и на входе будет параметр.